# XML Schema - Validate one attribute, based on the value of another

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to be able to validate an attribute in an element, based on the value of another attribute. Something like this.

```
<Root>
    <Vehicle type="Unicycle" numWheels="1" />
    <Vehicle type="Bicycle" numWheels="2" />
</Root>
```

The requirement would be that if the Vehicle types is 'Unicycle', then numWheels must be 1. Otherwise I don't care how many wheels it has.

I have something like this as a starting point for the type, where I want to impose the restriction.

```
<!-- Number of Wheels restrictions -->
<xsd:simpleType name="NumberOfWheelsType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I must confess I am not quite sure where to start to create the restriction that I want, so any guidance would be appreciated.

I am using xmllint to validate the Schema which I think will restrict me to XML Schema 1.0 (correct me if I am wrong, because I cannot prove this one way or the other).

Answer (score 2):

Cross-constraints across attribute values require XSD 1.1, and as you correctly surmise, xmllint supports only XSD 1.0. You will need to add some other validation technology to your pipeline: either XSD 1.1, or Schematron, or a custom validator written in XSLT.

Comment: I had rather come to the conclusion that I might need to move up to XSD 1.1. Assuming I can do that what do I need to look for to achieve my goal?